# Changing Nav li to active using jquery - Bootsrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the Active class in my navbar (using bootstrap), when I click on the link.

This is my html:

```
            <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="brand" href="#">Phonebook</a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I've tried the follwing jQuery code that I got from an answer here in the site, but it doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.nav li a').click(function (e) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
                $this.addClass('active');
            }
            debugger;
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Are trying to mark `li` or `a` as active? You really don't need to do both.

Answer (score 1):

You're complicating it :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav li').on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YtLB2/1/)

and why would you add hash links to the anchors, and then use preventDefault in the event handler ?

Comment: I've tried this and still doesn't work. i work with ASPX files. maybe it's something in the page configuration?